# Handling multiple swipe events HTML & Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, swipe

I am currently trying to make a mobile multiplayer game based on HTML5 and Javascript. I use the jQuery Plugin "touchwipe" to handle the swipe events made in different divs like this:

```
$('#play1').touchwipe({
            wipeLeft:   function(){ if(d1!="right") d1 = "left"; },
            wipeRight:  function(){ if(d1!="left") d1 = "right" },
            wipeUp:     function(){ if(d1!="up") d1 = "down" },
            wipeDown:   function(){ if(d1!="down") d1 = "up"}               
        })  

$('#play2').touchwipe({
            wipeLeft:   function(){ if(d2!="right") d2 = "left" },
            wipeRight:  function(){ if(d2!="left") d2 = "right"   },
            wipeUp:     function(){ if(d2!="up") d2 = "down"  },
            wipeDown:   function(){ if(d2!="down") d2 = "up" }
        })
```

It works well when the players aren't swiping at the same time but what can I do to call an event if both player swipe at the same time (for example player 1 swipes left and player 2 swipes right at the same time so d1 = "left" and d2 = "right")?

Answer (score 0):

Phones themselves do not handle multiple swipe gestures. You can see how this works by putting 2 fingers on a touch screen. Swipe 1 in 1 direction, and the other in another the opposite direction. There is no queue to sequence the events so only the one who captures the hardware will interrupt. Thus the 2nd event will never even be triggered in the hardware level, so it cannot queue up in the software.

Expanding the game to 2 devices, or using click events (easier to encapsulate and queue) might work better.